# How to display array data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want what is in the `colors` array (hex codes for now) to display in the template `<color-block>` that I have created.

```js
Vue.component('color-block', {
    props: ['hexcolor'],
    template:
    `
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"
     {{ colors.hex }}
    </div>
    `
});
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
     colors: [
        { color: 'Red', hex: '#FF0000' },
        { color: 'Blue', hex: '#0000FF' }
        ]
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>
<div id="app">
    <color-block v-for="hex in colors" :colorBlock="hex">
    </color-block>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/168833/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems:

- Your demo sets `:colorBlock="..."`, but the prop is actually named `hexcolor` in the component, so the setting should be `:hexcolor="..."`
- In the `v-for` loop, `hex` is an object (`{color: 'Red', hex: '#FF0000'}`), but I assume you only wanted to pass the hex color code, so the setting should be `:hexcolor="hex.hex"`.
- Your `color-block` template is missing a closing bracket after the `class`
- Your `color-block` template references `colors.hex`, but `colors` is not part of the component (it's part of `app`'s data). You probably meant to display the value of the component's prop (`hexcolor`).

*Demo with corrections made:*

```js
Vue.component('color-block', {
  props: ['hexcolor'],
  template: `
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      {{ hexcolor }}
    </div>
    `
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      colors: [
        { color: 'Red', hex: '#FF0000' },
        { color: 'Blue', hex: '#0000FF' }
      ]
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>
<div id="app">
  <color-block v-for="hex in colors" :hexcolor="hex.hex">
  </color-block>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is what happens when I try and use something I'm not familiar with for a work project before I'm ready.